# Cairo font size in Knitr

Tags: r, font-size, knitr

I am trying to set the font size in a Cairo device, but the `pointsize` argument seems to set the size of the points in the plot, and not the font size. I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
library(maptools)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
@

<<fig1, dev='cairo_pdf', dev.args=list(family ="CMU Serif", pointsize=12), fig.keep='last'>>=
plot(meuse, pch=16)
legend("topleft", "Example Text")
@
<<fig2, dev='cairo_png',fig.ext='png',dev.args=list(family ="CMU Serif", pointsize=2), fig.keep='last'>>=
plot(meuse, pch=16)
legend("topleft", "Example Text")
@
\end{document}
```

`fig1` has large points and normal text, and `fig2` has identical text but tiny points. [image: figure1] [image: figure2]

Comment: Provided that this question is about Knitr and not really LaTeX related, beside the fact that it is used inside a LaTeX document, you might get better answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: [Yihui](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui) recently [fixed this issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/e430c60d7da595b62455a946f8b27d1dc0bd395c), following [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613467/increasing-the-size-of-axis-labels-in-knitr-with-r-markdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R base graphics, the font size is usually set via the argument `cex(.something)`. In this specific case, you can use the `cex` argument of the `legend()` function, e.g.

```
plot(meuse, pch=16)
legend("topleft", "Example Text", cex=2)
```