# Increasing the size of axis labels in KnitR with R Markdown

Tags: r, graphics, knitr

In KnitR with R Markdown, I can use `dev.args=list(pointsize=18)` to pass the `pointsize` argument to the graphics device.

That increases the size of the points in the plot, and also the amount of space around the plot, but it doesn't seem to affect the size of the axis labels. It seems like I need to use something like `par(cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5)`, too.

Is that as expected?

Here are three example code chunks with the images produced:

First the defaults:

````
```{r fig1}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```
````

[image: defaults]

Now use `dev.args=list(pointsize=18)`

````
```{r fig2, dev.args=list(pointsize=18)}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```
````

[image: using pointsize=18]

Now also use `par(cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5)`

````
```{r fig3, dev.args=list(pointsize=18)}
par(cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```
````

[image: pointsize=13 and cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5]

Comment: I guess this is much like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880627/cairo-font-size-in-knitr), and the answer is: use `par(cex.blah)`

Comment: You could alternatively use the more compact call `plot(x, y, cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing with `par(cex.blah)` endlessly, you can consider vector graphics instead of raster graphics. For example, you can use the SVG device, and scale the plot without quality loss.

````
```{r fig4, dev='svg', fig.width=6, fig.height=6, out.width='600px'}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(x,y)
```
````

---

Update: for the original problem using the `png` device, the `pointsize` argument was not passed to the recording device. I have [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/e430c60d7da595b62455a946f8b27d1dc0bd395c) the problem in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) (>= v1.5.22).

Comment: I like the suggestion. But I guess my real question is why does `dev='png'` with `dev.args=list(pointsize=18)` behave differently from `png("file.png", pointsize=18)` within R?

Comment: Is there a detailed reference on R markdown where I can find all these options e.g. `dev.args=list(pointsize=18)`. I am only discovering rmarkdown from various SO questions. I have seen the cheatsheet at rstudio but that is insufficient for a beginner.